# Node js trouble intallation after removing nodejs, to update to latest stable version

Tags: upgrade, nodejs

I was using the old version of nodejs. Then i removed the old version using "rm rf- " command, but it was still showing the version when i run the "node -v " command, so i searched and deleted some more files. Now when i try to install:- it does not install and show the following message:-

sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
npm is already the newest version (3.5.2-0ubuntu4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 70 not upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to figure this out is use:
`whereis node` this will help you pinpoint where the current package is.
navigate there and make sure the package is not a symlink (because if it is, apt-get might not work for you)

also, as far as I remember there was something called `nodejs-legacy` so make sure you don't have this installed, too.

Once all is uninstalled I highly suggest using node version manager:
https://github.com/creationix/nvm
(helpful hint: read readme and installer output VERY carefully to avoid installation issues)

I suggest using nvm, because ubuntu repository doesn't keep node version up to date, and it's way easier to switch between them if your project happens to use older release as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks @janmyszkier...successfully resolved the issue.And surely NVM is the best way to install the nodejs and upgrading version.